# Enforce https without www for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, subdomain

I have phpbb forum which I would like to be viewed only over SSL.

For an example it will be like

If www.subdomain.domain.com - https://subdomain.domain.com
Or 
If subdomain.domain.com - https://subdomain.domain.com

I tried several answers which I could find non of them are working properly. Some returning 500 internal server error some aren't enforcing only SSL.

Can anyone suggest me something which I could use in htaccess?

Comment: I posted an answer bellow, if you are happy with the answer ,please accept it otherwise let me know how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```